# Add a column with a rank to an rdd in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, rank

Unfortunately we still have to use spark 1.0.0 and need to work with RDDs. 
I have a RDD that is created from a CSV file.

```
val serialRDD = sc.textFile(path)
```

If we print each line of the RDD, we get something like this (an id and a string) :

```
1929  abc
2384  def
8753  ghi
3893  jkl
```

I want to be able to add another column being another id, which is going to be a string like "SERIAL-" where RANK would be 1,2,3 etc autoincrementing by 1

The output should be like:

```
1929  abc  SERIAL-1
2384  def  SERIAL-2
8753  ghi  SERIAL-3
3893  jkl  SERIAL-4
```

How could I get this done using RDD?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `zipWithIndex` and `map` to get it done :

```
serialRDD.zipWithIndex.map{ case (r, i) => (r._1, r._2, s"SERIAL-${i+1}") }
```

I used string interpolation to get the `SERIAL-X` string. I also incremented the index because `zipWithIndex` starts at the index 0.